# Repeating Local Notification in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to make a notification, Whever app is installed, it automatically set alarm/notification every 1st of month and upon clicking that notification it opens a specific activity of the application

Here is my code for alarm manager

```
 // get a Calendar object with current time
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    // add 5 minutes to the calendar object
    cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 5);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra(MESSAGE);

    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 10, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    // Get the AlarmManager service
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
```

I have made an alarm class

```
 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
 {
   try {
         Intent newIntent = new Intent(context, Appointment.class);
         context.startActivity(newIntent);
        } 
   catch (Exception e) 
    {
       Toast.makeText(context, "There was an error somewhere, but we still received an alarm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
}
```

My problem is, i want to set it as a repeating notification, each month on 1st. The alarm code, I have it in my mainActivity. How can i set it that it will repeat each month

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `Schedule a repeating alarm can be achieved by setRepeating() of AlarmManager()`

`public void setRepeating (int type, long triggerAtMillis, long intervalMillis, PendingIntent operation)`

> Hope you can achieve your goal by checking which month is and modify the `INTERVAL_DAY *28` Or `INTERVAL_DAY*30` OR `INTERVAL_DAY*31` by setting flags and all that.

```
 am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY*30, sender);
```

Comment: Check out these link for better understanding[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Comment: What happens if this code is run again and again before a month

Comment: @MuhammadUmar as `setRepeating()` contains `pendingIntent` which fired off only `triggering time arrives` in your case  `every month`. Thus `only pendingIntent` fires off `every month` what you exactly asked for.