# How to send a local repeating notification in certain days?

Tags: java, android

I have a reminders app, I made a UI that [looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCvO6.png) where the user can pick multiple days and the hour that he wants to be reminded on. For example, I can select Monday and Tuesday at 15:00 and I should be reminded those days at that given hour. But I can´t figure out how to make this work (mainly, the mutiple days thing). Any ideas?

Comment: may be you will want check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19427160/12355947

Answer (score 2):

You can send a local repeating notification with the help of `AlarmManager`. `setRepeating()` function can be used to schedule notifications.

similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14161945/repeating-local-notification-in-android), Check this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) for better understanding.